# Django Graphene form validation with integer field

Tags: django, graphene-django

Here's my simple scenario. I have a model that has two mandatory fields name and age:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I'm using Django model form with Graphene

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'age')

class PersonType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PersonMutation(DjangoModelFormMutation):
    class Meta:
        form_class = PersonForm

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    person_mutation = PersonMutation.Field()
```

Lets say a person fills age field but not name field. I can then send a mutation query

```
mutation {
  personMutation(input: {age: 25, name: ""}) {
    errors {
      field
      messages
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following response, which is exactly what I want. This response is easy to go through and I get  name field validation message.

```
{
  "data": {
    "personMutation": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "field": "name",
          "messages": [
            "This field is required."
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But what if the user fills name but not age? What kind of mutation query should I make?

If I make

```
mutation {
  personMutation(input: {name: "my name"}) {
    errors {
      field
      messages
    }
  }
}
```

I get the response below. That is a horrible message, I can't show that to user. Also response json format is different than before.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Argument \"input\" has invalid value {name: \"my name\"}.\nIn field \"age\": Expected \"Int!\", found null.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I try to put `age: null` or `age: ""` as input parameter it's not any better. So how can I get Django's "This field is required" validation message when age is not set?

Comment: What response do you get when you only insert age and no name at all not even an empy string?

Comment: Giving only age gives the same unwanted error message: Argument input has invalid... So the issue is there as well but you can kinda go around it by giving an empty string as parameter. But for other types that is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphene gives an instant error message because in the model both fields are `blank=False` (default) that makes the field in the form `required=True` ([see doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)). 
I guess if you query with only age and no name at all not even an empty string you would get a comparable error message.

Some ideas on how to avoid this problem:

1. Make the fields `blank=True` in your model. Then you need to check in your backend if the values are set and generate a custom error message if not.
2. Make the fields `blank=False` (default) in your model and leave it to the frontend to check if the fields are set. E.g. make the "send" button disabled if not all required values are set. Which is the nicer way I think.

Comment: Yup, these were the options that I also could come up with but hoped that there would be a way to give null values to query variables.

Comment: you could set `null=True` in your model. But I'm actually not sure if that will work.